# how to store value of index of an array during while loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

```
int main()
{
   int abc[2][2];
   int i,j,q,r,u,k;
   char *A = malloc(sizeof(*A));

   abc[0][0] = 1;
   abc[1][0] = 0;
   abc[0][1] = 7;
   abc[1][1] = 480;

    do
    {
        if( abc[1][1]>abc[0][1])
        {

            q = floor((abc[1][1] - 1)/abc[0][1]);
            r = abc[1][1] - q*abc[0][1];
            abc[1][0] = q*abc[0][0] + abc[1][0];
            abc[1][1] = r;
        }

        if( abc[0][1]>abc[1][1])
        {
            q = floor((abc[0][1] - 1)/abc[1][1]);
            r = abc[0][1] - q*abc[1][1];
            abc[0][0] = q*abc[1][0] + abc[0][0];
            abc[0][1] = r;
        }

        u = abc[0][0];
        A[k] = abc[1][0];

    } while (abc[0][1]>1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to store each the values for the index - `abc[1][0]` in array `A[]` so that I cant use that array further but I'm stuck at storing all the values

Comment: `char *A = malloc(sizeof(*A));` malloc 1 char? but why? `A[k] = abc[1][0];` Use of uninitialized variable `k` to reference an array? but why?

Comment: `A` is not much of an array. It points at a single `char` of storage.

Comment: You want ot make a copy of `abc`? Why not make another `A[2][2]` and copy the values in a nested loop pair?

Comment: @John3136 I want uninitialized  array

Comment: @Yunnosch I dont need full array just abc[1][0]

Comment: (referring to OP comment before the most previous one) a) Why? b) So what is the problem? Another `array[2][2]` will be uninitialised if you do not initialise it.

Comment: @June. You are mallocing 1 character not an array. You are saying `A[k]` when k has no specific value (it could be anything). The only legal value for k in this case is 0 (since you have allocated 1 char).

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to do. Could add an example of how you want A to look?

Comment: If you only want to copy the single value abc[1][0] then use a normal variable. If you want to copy all values from one "row" or "column" then make an array[2]. An array[1][0] would be of size 0.

Comment: Show or explain in prose how you intend to use `A`.

Comment: what on god's green earth is this program supposed to do?

Comment: You are doing integer division. The `floor()` function is pointless.

Comment: BTW: `char *A = malloc(sizeof(*A));` should probably be `char *A = malloc(N * sizeof(*A));` where N is the number of elements you want in A

Comment: BTW: `k` is uninitialized. At least do `k = 0;`

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Could you phrase your applicable question in a more matter-of-fact way?

Comment: @jcarpenter2 I just need all the values at index abc[1][0] I'm trying to use those values for RSA algorithm, instead of using euclidean algorithm i'm using this

Comment: There is only one value at `abc[1][0]`. There is confusion about what you mean by "all the values". Pleae use prose to explain with more words. Do want to log the values which are at that location, e.g. store on from each time through a loop?

Comment: @Yunnosch yup "store on from each time through a loop"

Comment: @Yunnosch when above do..while loop execute its generates multiple values at  abc[1][0] not only one during every iteration

Comment: Ok look at all the comments: a) malloc more space b) init k c) rethink the `floor()`. Then increment k each time through the loop.

Comment: I don't think so. But please indicate the several places the values is changed; those you want to store. If it is e.g. twice per loop, then double the malloced size and write once to `A[k]` and once to `A[k+1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to record the value of `abc[1][0]` in the end of each loop, you can do like this:

```
int* A = malloc(1000 * sizeof(*A));  // Note: Room for 1000 values
k = 0;

....
....
do
{
    ....
    ....

    if (k < 1000)
    {
        A[k] = abc[1][0];
        ++k;
    }
} while (abc[0][1]>1);

// Print the recorded values
printf("Recorded %d values\n", k);
int t;
for (t = 0; t < k; ++t) printf("Value[%d]=%d\n", t, A[t]);
```

This will record the first 1000 values.

If you want to be able to record "any" number of values, you shall take a look at `realloc` so that you can assign more memory when you reach 1000

Comment: OP wants to store more than one value each time through the loop.

Comment: @Yunnosch - What makes you think that?

Comment: The comment by OP "do..while loop execute its generates multiple values at abc[1][0] not only one during every iteration".

Comment: @Yunnosch Hmmm... well, it's a bit unclear but looking at the code tells me that OP changes `abc[1][0]` one time in each loop. I guess OP wants to record that new value.

Comment: @4386427 Yes want to store/record each new value in array A[], after every iteration

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Good point. I guess it is just too unclear. 4386427, this is why I do not dare making an answer yet. My respect.

Comment: @4386427 I tried your answer but its only storing 0

Comment: @june See updated answer. It shows how to print the recorded values